# git-svn merging when branches don't line up

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I suspect this may simply be an impedance mismatch between `git` and `svn`, but I wanted to ask the SO community for advice.

I am working on a project that uses `svn` for version control. That's not going to change, and I have no control over it. I've happily been doing my work on my branch using `git-svn`. However, I ran into an odd problem related to the strange way the SVN project was set up.

In SVN, the project looks like this:

- *project root*

  - branches

    - MyBranch

      - Dir1
      - Dir2
      - *etc.*
  - trunk

    - Proj_Main

      - Dir1
      - Dir2
      - *etc.*

.git/config:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = http://svn-repo
    fetch = project/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    branches = project/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = project/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

When the branches were created, they were created one level below `trunk`. I had no control over this either.

When I try to merge from `MyBranch` to `trunk`, my tree merges one level up. That is, `MyBranch/Dir1` has no relationship to `trunk/Proj_Main/Dir1`. In `svn` natively, it does understand this relationship, and I can merge using `svn` tools, but `git` is lost.

Is there a way I can tell `git` that `master` points to `trunk/Proj_Main` instead of just `trunk`?

Comment: when mapping branches between svn and git, for specific branches, you can specify exactly where the branches are. If you specified `-s` when initializing git-svn then it assumed that there was a branch called trunk there... but you could specify trunk/whatever instead if that's what suits your environment. Perhaps you could also add the svn-related sections of .git/config? At least the lines that are set up as `branches` or `fetch`.

Comment: I did use -s to initialize the repo. The question is, how can I fix it after the fact?

Comment: your comment suggests that what I want is possible, I'm just not sophisticated enough to figure it out on my own :)

Answer (score 2):

Edit the fetch line to something like:

```
fetch = project/trunk/Proj_Main:refs/remotes/trunk
```

That should do.... *however*, I don't know if you will have to fetch again from revision 1 for such a change to work correctly.

Comment: can I simply edit the .git/config, or do I need to run some command?

Comment: Editing the file will be fine on any decent text editor.... you could then try `git svn fetch`.. and good luck.

Comment: I ran into a complication... the server at http://svn-repo actually hosts many SVN repositories. Pulling the whole thing into my git exhausts disk space. When I edit the .git/config as you suggest and run `git svn fetch`, it tries to pull __all__ of the repos, and not just `project`

Comment: It sounds even more like you should take the time to set up the layout of the svn repo with the appropriate `branches/fetch` lines and **not** just use `git svn init -s`

Answer (score 0):

@eftshift0 had the right approach. Sometimes there is no salvaging a bad situation. I made sure everything was sync'd with SVN and started over again.

```
git svn clone -r<start>:HEAD http://svn-repo/project \
    --prefix=mine/ \
    --trunk=trunk/Proj_Main --branches=branches --tags=tags \
    --no-minimize-url
```

Since this is a very mature SVN repo, and I don't care about history from 5 years ago, I limited the scope of my clone, for the sake of time.

The `--prefix` is based on advice in the [git-svn docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

Rather than `-s` or `--stdlayout`, I explicitly specified how things were laid out in SVN. Note that early attempts to apply this approach encountered a [git-svn bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/AUrsnPcJvR0) fetching, probably related to a deleted SVN branch. That's another reason for limiting the scope of the fetch.

The `--no-minimize-url` is due to the fact that other repos exist at the server. Without this switch, git-svn pushes up a level and considers **all** the repos in trying to resolve branches, merges, and such. That was not a good thing for me.